# read input in an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created an Eclipse RCP application. I want to read an input from the user when the program runs. How can I do that? Please any one help me with a sample code.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: A bit of clarification about the nature of the user input would be really helpful.

Comment: when I run my application I have to take an ip address from the user. using the ip address my application will continue its process. How can I create a text field, where the user can enter the ip. I want to read the input in my program also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you application is not headless: we usually use dialog windows to capture user input. eclipse RCP/SWT has some dialog classes, it's quite the same as doing it in swing.

For an easy start: [JFace's InputDialog](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/JFacesInputDialog.htm) (available in eclipse RCP applications)

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for your reply. I am very new to the RCP aplications. I just want to read a line from the user. Can you please describe your answer?

Comment: Have a look at the code snippet behind the link. It reads some input from a user.

Comment: ?? The target is this one: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/JFacesInputDialog.htm - and it works and has code.